# MVC Partial view update and Error redirection

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Sample/Test",
    dataType: "html",
    async: false,
    success: function (resp) {
    }
})
```

Am making an Ajax call to Controller and my Controller returns the Partial View **(ActionResult)** and i update the HTML of the particular div in the page. Looks good.

In case if there are any Error happening in the controller it returns an Error page which is returned to the Ajax Success.

I have 2 problems here

1. In Straight forward scenario the Error page is set in the partial Div
2. In some scenarios am finding dynamically div id and then updating that section alone. As Error page is the div is undefined and nothing happens.

How do i make it redirect to the Error page instead of partially updating in case of Error.

Even i tried with try catch where in Catch i returned the View instead of partial view. But that didnt worked.

I tried redirecting from below code as well

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Error/Error");
}
```

This also returns the Error page to ajax success.

What is the best way to redirect to full Error page as i have multiple ajax calls in my application?

Other approach i came across is to find the text in the success and redirect there. is that a good approach ?

Any common way to implement that way as i have ajax calls in multiple places.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check Database values by using If conditions by using getting count if any error occurs then return back to view other wise return to partial view.

Comment: Did you tried ? that didn't work. it still updates partially. i mentioned in my question

Comment: return RedirectToAction("Error", "Error"); Try this

Answer (score 0):

If your AJAX is calling a controller method that updates a partial view then it needs to look like this:

```
public PartialViewResult Test(string myVar)
{
    return PartialView("_MyPartialView", MyViewModel);
}
```

Then you need to get the ajax to update the div your partial view is contain in:

```
function UpdateTest() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Sample/Test',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { myVar: "@Model.MyVar" },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#partial-div").html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes that works completely fine! my issue is in case of Error. I mentioned that in my question

Comment: Sorry I completely misunderstood the question. You can use a JavaScriptResult to redirect to a page from an AJAX request:         "public JavaScriptResult ErrorPage()
        {
            return JavaScript("window.location = 'Error/'");
        }"

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   try
     {
     }
   catch(Exception e)
   { 
    //handle error
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500);
   }    
return 
}


function UpdateTest() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Sample/Test',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { myVar: "@Model.MyVar" },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#partial-div").html(result);
        },
error: function() {
       document.location.href = '/error'; 
    }       
    });
}
```